# Post To FB Wall Of App User

Tags: jquery, facebook, posts

I bought a FB script on codecanyon, the script allows users to log into my site using the facebook button. I created the app, the log in part is working just fine. The problem is this script was also suppose to let me post on the FB wall of the users of my app. That part doesn't work. Can some please help me resolve this.

I can email users but evidently this guy forgot to add the FB post part. 
here's the script.

```
 /*
 * Created by Ryan Davies, All rights reserved
 * http://www.rnrit.co.uk
 * Date: Sep 3, 2010
 * Time: 12:23:10 PM
 */
ob_start();
session_start(); 
$output = "";

// include required files
require "../includes/config.php";
require "../includes/database.php";
require "../includes/facebook.php";
require "../includes/language.php";

// check for logged in user
if(isLoggedIn() != "true" || $_SESSION['userType'] != "admin") {
header('Location: login.php');
die();
}

// check for delete user
if(isset($_POST['delID'])) {
$del = new database();
$del->connect();
$where = "id = '" . $_POST['delID'] . "'";
$del->select('username','users',$where);
$result = $del->getResult();
$del->delete('users',$where);
$output = '<div class="ok"><img src="../images/tickbig.png" alt="OK" title="OK"    class="float_outside_error"><p>'.outputLan("userAdminPage","user deleted").'</p><script   type="text/javascript">hideError();</script></div>';
// delete profile page
unlink('../users/'.$result['username'].'.php');
}


// email all users
if(isset($_POST['emPost'])) {

$errors = 0;

// check input
if($_POST['subject'] == "") { $errors = 1; $output .= '<li>You must enter a     subject</li>'; }    
if($_POST['from'] == "") { $errors = 1; $output .= '<li>You must enter an email address</li>'; }    
if($_POST['reply'] == "") { $errors = 1; $output .= '<li>You must enter a reply to address</li>'; } 
if($_POST['message'] == "") { $errors = 1; $output .= '<li>You must enter a message</li>'; }    

// check for errors before sending
if($errors == 0) {
// all ok, send message
$message = $_POST['message'];
$message = str_replace("\n.", "\n..", $message);
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $sender =  $_POST['from'];
$reply = $_POST['reply'];
    $headers = 'From: ' . $sender . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: ' . $reply . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

// loop through users
$db = new database();
$db->connect();
$where = "contact = 'yes'";
$db->select('*','users');
$result = $db->getResult();
$rows = $db->getRows();
for($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i ++ ) {

    $to = $result[$i]['email'];
    $name = $result[$i]['name'];

    $Nmessage = "";
    $Nmessage = "Dear " . $name . "\n\n" . $message;

if(mail($to, $subject, $Nmessage, $headers)) {
    // message sent
    $output .= '<li>'.outputLan("userAdminPage","email sent") . $to . '</li>';
} else {
    // error
    $errors = 1;
    $output .= '<li>'. outputLan("userAdminPage","email problem") . $to .     '</li>';
}

} // end of loop

if($errors == 0) {
    $output = '<div class="ok"><img src="../images/tickbig.png" alt="Ok"   title="Ok" class="float_outside_error"><ul>'.$output.'</ul><script   type="text/javascript">hideError();</script></div>';
} else {
    $output = '<div class="error"><img src="../images/crossBig.png" alt="Error"   title="Error" class="float_outside_error"><ul>'.$output.'</ul><script  type="text/javascript">hideError();</script></div>';
}

} else {
    $output = '<div class="error"><img src="../images/crossBig.png" alt="Error"  title="Error" class="float_outside_error"><ul>'.$output.'</ul><script type="text/javascript">hideError();</script></div>';
}
} // end of emPost
```

Here's the form

```
    <div id="fb_post">
    <h2><img src="../images/facebook.png" alt="fb" title="<?php echo   outputLan("userAdminPage","fb image title"); ?>"><?php echo outputLan("userAdminPage","fb  post"); ?></h2>
     <p><?php echo outputLan("userAdminPage","fb blurb"); ?></p>

    <form method="post" action="useradmin.php">

        <label for="title"><?php echo outputLan("userAdminPage","post  title"); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="input_field" size="110">

        <label for="name"><?php echo outputLan("userAdminPage","post name"); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="input_field" size="110">

        <label for="caption"><?php echo outputLan("userAdminPage","post caption"); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="caption" id="caption" class="input_field" size="110">

        <label for="desc"><?php echo outputLan("userAdminPage","post body"); ?></label>
        <textarea name="desc" id="desc" class="input_field" cols="110" rows="5"></textarea>

        <label for="image"><?php echo outputLan("userAdminPage","post image"); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="image" id="image" class="input_field" size="110">

        <label for="url"><?php echo outputLan("userAdminPage","post url"); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="url" id="url" class="input_field" size="110">

        <input type="submit" name="fbPost" id="fbPost" value="<?php echo  outputLan("userAdminPage","post submit"); ?>" class="input_field submit">

    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd like to post to the FB wall of the users of my app.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the script is prompting the user for the publish_stream extended permission. You can tell if it is or not by clicking the Facebook button, logging in, and it should say that the app needs permission to write on your wall.  If the user doesn't authorize this or you aren't asking for permission to do this, the request will fail.